# Does DbContext need MemoryCache or Redis in Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have multiple lookup tables in a SQL Server database. Tables are used in application dropdown menus.

**AddressType:**

- Home
- Business

**ProductType:**

- Books
- Food
- Electronics

Instead of continually reading database lookup tables, team wants to apply `MemoryCache` or `Redis Cache` (to reduce database load, and increase in-memory performance). However, we learned that Entity Framework Core `DbContext` already has caching.

So in this case, would there be any value in caching looking tables, if after a certain amount of reads, the `DbContext` does this already?
Would adding more caching code for `MemoryCache/Redis` over `DbContext` help? Or would it be an unnecessary layer?

Comment: Hi, It depends on your requirement. You can use memory cache provided by EF Core. But if you have multiple servers you will need distributed caching and for that you will need NCache, Redis etc.